# Recursion Depth Exceeded/ Kernel Death Concatenating Tensors for NLP Neural Network

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, jupyter-notebook, tail-recursion

**UPDATE**

I managed to solve the problem by creating a list that contained both the features (reviews) and labels (overall rating), then used mapping / apply (if using panda dataframes) in order to transform them into tensors. At that point, I used the from_tensor_slices method of tensorflow to have the features/labels ready to be trained on.

**Original Problem**

I am currently working on a NLP project to help learn Python/Tensorflow. My program takes in reviews, encodes them, converts them to tensors and tensor datasets, then feeds it into a neural network. The problem I am encountering is a "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object" which stems from concatenating the tensors into a single tensor dataset.

When I attempt to access an element from the dataset (either through an iter object or through training the network) the recursion error appears.

**What I've done:**

If I reduce the total number of reviews that I process from the original 9000-ish to 1500, it works fine.

If I use

```
import sys 
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)
```

then the juypter kernel dies instead of giving me the recursion error.

**Relevant Code** (I think)

```
#encode the text

encoded_reviews=[]
for j in trimmed_review:
    encoded_reviews.append(encoder.encode(j))

#creating tensorflow datasets for training
def labeler(review, rating):
    return review, rating
#pairing the labels (good/bad game) with the encoded reviews
encoded_review_rating_list=[]
for i,j in enumerate(encoded_reviews):
    encoded_review_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(tf.cast(j, dtype='int64'))
    encoded_review_rating_list.append(encoded_review_dataset.map(lambda x: labeler(x,ratings[i])))

 #Combine the list of review:score sets into a single tensor dataset.
encoded_review_ratings = encoded_review_rating_list[0]
#test_var_tensor=tf.constant()
for single_dataset in encoded_review_rating_list[1:]:
    encoded_review_ratings=encoded_review_ratings.concatenate(single_dataset)

#Shuffle the datasets to avoid any biases.
buffer_size = len(encoded_reviews)
all_labeled_data = encoded_review_ratings.shuffle(
    buffer_size, reshuffle_each_iteration=False)

##Split the encoded words into training and test datasets, take size amount of data that goes into the training set
training_ratio=0.6
take_size= round(len(encoded_reviews)*training_ratio)
batch_size=30

#Organizing our training and validation data, the padded shapes are set to the longest review (as specified by None keywords)
train_data = all_labeled_data.take(take_size)
train_data = train_data.padded_batch(batch_size, padded_shapes=((None,), (1,)))

test_data = all_labeled_data.skip(take_size)
test_data = test_data.padded_batch(batch_size, padded_shapes=((None,), (1,)))
```

**Error Code from accessing a tensor in the dataset**

````
next_feature, next_label = next(iter(test_data))
        
print (next_feature, next_label)



```---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RecursionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-e941c005ed79> in <module>
----> 1 next_feature, next_label = next(iter(test_data))
      2 
      3 print (next_feature, next_label)

~\anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\data\ops\dataset_ops.py in __iter__(self)
    416     if (context.executing_eagerly()
    417         or ops.get_default_graph()._building_function):  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 418       return iterator_ops.OwnedIterator(self)
    419     else:
    420       raise RuntimeError("__iter__() is only supported inside of tf.function "

~\anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\data\ops\iterator_ops.py in __init__(self, dataset, components, element_spec)
    592           context.context().device_spec.device_type != "CPU"):
    593         with ops.device("/cpu:0"):
--> 594           self._create_iterator(dataset)
    595       else:
    596         self._create_iterator(dataset)

~\anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\data\ops\iterator_ops.py in _create_iterator(self, dataset)
    598   def _create_iterator(self, dataset):
    599     # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 600     dataset = dataset._apply_options()
    601 
    602     # Store dataset reference to ensure that dataset is alive when this iterator

~\anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\data\ops\dataset_ops.py in _apply_options(self)
    356 
    357     dataset = self
--> 358     options = self.options()
    359     if options.experimental_threading is not None:
    360       t_options = options.experimental_threading

~\anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\data\ops\dataset_ops.py in options(self)
    347     options = Options()
    348     for input_dataset in self._inputs():
--> 349       input_options = input_dataset.options()
    350       if input_options is not None:
    351         options = options.merge(input_options)

... last 1 frames repeated, from the frame below ...

~\anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\data\ops\dataset_ops.py in options(self)
    347     options = Options()
    348     for input_dataset in self._inputs():
--> 349       input_options = input_dataset.options()
    350       if input_options is not None:
    351         options = options.merge(input_options)

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
````

Answer (score 0):

Providing solution in answer section for the benefit of community. Thank you @Accommodator for the update.

> I managed to solve the problem by creating a list that contained both
> the features (reviews) and labels (overall rating), then used mapping
> / apply (if using panda dataframes) in order to transform them into
> tensors. At that point, I used the from_tensor_slices method of
> tensorflow to have the features/labels ready to be trained on